# Firebase schedule run a function after 10 minute

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to store data from my React Native Application. My application basically lets users reserve a spot. This spot should be automatically deleted after 10 minutes in case the user doesn't arrive in time. So, I wanted to know how is it possible to schedule a function to run 10 minutes after the creation of a reservation instance. I've tried using Cloud Functions and Pub/Sub but couldn't find a way to do the following using these services.

Code:

```
exports.onCreateReservation = functions.database
  .ref('/reservations/{id}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
    const project = 'proj';
    const location = 'us-central1';
    const queue = 'cancel';

    const userId = snapshot.key;
    const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient();
    const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue);
    const expirationAtSeconds = Date.now() + 1000;

    const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/cancelReservation`;
    const task = {
      httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        url,
        body: JSON.stringify({id: userId}),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      },
      scheduleTime: {
        expirationAtSeconds,
      },
    };

    await tasksClient.createTask({
      parent: queuePath,
      task,
    });
  });

exports.cancelReservation = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.body;

  try {
    await admin.database().ref(`/reservations/${id}`).remove();
    res.send(200);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

I keep getting this error in the functions logs after the onCreateReservation function is executed. It keeps finishing with status 'error'

```
Error: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: invalid encoding
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in `runAfter` trigger type.

You can either schedule a function at a regular interval and then check for expired content, or use Cloud Tasks to trigger for the individual expired nodes as Doug describes in his blog post [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

Comment: Is it possible to do the following for Realtime database?

Comment: The process has in the blog post I linked can be made to work on any database. I recommend giving it a try, and posting with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Comment: Hey @kmagued. Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Still working on it. Sorry for the late reply.